# How to test a function that triggers a setTimeout in jasmine 2.5?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
PlayOscillator(hz: number = 400, durationInSeconds: number = 1){
    this._Oscillators[0].frequency.value = hz;
    this._Oscillators[0].connect(this._MainGainNode);
    this._activeOscillatorIndex = 0;

setTimeout(() => {
    console.info("time out called");
    this._Oscillators[this._activeOscillatorIndex].disconnect(this._MainGainNode);
this._Oscillators[this._activeOscillatorIndex] = undefined;
}, durationInSeconds * 1000);
}
```

I want to test `typeof` `this._Oscillators[0]` after the setTimeout was executed but I am not able to do it. All the solutions that I have found here recommend functions that are not available in jasmine 2.5

I have so far

```
       it('Should switch from one oscillator to another',()=>{
                let wap = webAudioApiProvider;
            expect(wap._Oscillators[0]).toBeUndefined();
            expect(()=>{wap.PlayOscillator(freq,duration)}).not.toThrow();
            expect(wap._Oscillators[0]).toBeUndefined();

        });
```

Comment: Where is your test code that you have so far?

Comment: Ah sorry I thought I pasted it. I will edit my question in 10 minutes when I go back from the grocery store. It is just a three line code with the it, expect, not throw. And toBe

Comment: @JLRishe updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a `done` parameter, which is supported since Jasmine 2.0:

```
it('Should switch from one oscillator to another', done => {
    let wap = webAudioApiProvider;
    expect(wap._Oscillators[0]).toBeUndefined();
    expect(()=>{wap.PlayOscillator(freq,duration)}).not.toThrow();

    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(wap._Oscillators[0]).toBeUndefined();
        done();
    }, duration * 1000 + 100); // add 100 to ensure this fires after the wap's timeout
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but I needed to ignore an error from tslint saying that "Cannot find name done", Maybe the typings for jasmine are not up to date.